# Multiselection with text and value

Tags: android, android-layout, view

What is the best View to utilize in Android to have a multiselection where you can set a separate string for the text and value?  Similar to how a drop down list has a display text value and a selected value.  I need to use something like the CheckedTextView, but with the ability to set a text and value, and retrieve the value in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a mulit selection dialog. Have a look at this [link](http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/03/android-multi-selection-dialogs/). It will explain how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to blessenm's suggestion, you could try [appsolut's library](http://code.google.com/p/android-collections-list-and-spinner-adapter/) - I've found it to be rather versatile and convenient in a variety of situations.